# Enabling the input field on selecting the dropdown

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

**HTML**

```
<mat-form-field class="id-name" >
     <mat-select placeholder="ID Card" formControlName="IDproof">
             <mat-option *ngFor="let IDproof of  IDproofs" [value]="IDproof.value" >
                 {{IDproof.viewValue}}
             </mat-option>
     </mat-select>

</mat-form-field>

<mat-form-field class="id-number" >
       <input matInput  >
</mat-form-field>
```

I am having on option list and one basic input field like shown in below image

[image]

How can I make the input field active after selecting the option from the option list. Until I select any one option from the list it should be disabled and after selecting that input field should be filled(required). How can I achieve this?

Comment: there is a ``disabled`` attribute that you can set in the ``<input>`` based on the value of the ``select``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `[disabled]` property,

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/enabling-the-input-in-selecting-the-dropdwon?file=app/input-overview-example.html)**

```
<input matInput [disabled]="myForm.get('IDproof').value">
```

Comment: `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'IDproof' ` Showing  this error.

Comment: Not `[disabled]="!myForm.get('IDproof').value"`?? with the `!`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/enabling-the-input-in-selecting-the-dropdwon?file=app/input-overview-example.html

Comment: plz check URL. I have create demo on Stackblitz.

Comment: Now i am unable todo validations for the input field,I want to validate it by using`formControlName` but by putting `formControlName` ,the input field will become active.

Comment: I am not understand .plz clarify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177923/discussion-between-venetian-village-and-krishna-rathore).